# What is the original color code of the placeholder text in Swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, colors, textfield, placeholder

Im making a swiftui application, with custom textfield, and I want to make the placeholder text color realistic, like the "real" placeholder text color

Comment: I think I found it! :     let originalplaceholdercolor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7137254902, green: 0.7137254902, blue: 0.7215686275, alpha: 1)

Comment: That doesn't account for dark mode. Try `UIColor.placeholderText` instead, I imagine that's what you're looking for. Surround with `Color(...)` to get the SwiftUI color from the UIKit color.